# Mi respuesta deja de tener sentido tras eliminar una etiqueta

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

La respuesta que di a la pregunta [Visual C# - Capturar evento clic de un botón](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15787/visual-c-capturar-evento-clic-de-un-bot%c3%b3n) asume que el autor de la pregunta está usando el IDE Visual Studio.

Asumí eso por estar la pregunta etiquetada con [c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) y [visual-studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio), además de por contener **Visual C#** en el título. Si el usuario no está usando dicho IDE la respuesta que di carece de sentido pues es específica para el IDE mencionado.

Se tomó la decisión de eliminar la etiqueta y he estado tentado de volver a añadirla, pero la edición de eliminación de la etiqueta fue revisada y aprobada, así que en lugar de añadir la etiqueta estoy pensando en eliminar mi respuesta.

¿Qué me aconsejan?

Comment: Creo que el problema está en que la pregunta era muy poco específica ene se sentido y ese trozo de códgo no tenía sentido tener la etiqueta visual studio ya que era simplemente c#, sin importar el IDE. Si crees que es importante haz una edición explicándolo para que sea revisado :)

Comment: @MiquelColl sospecho que el autor original de la pregunta usa MSVC, pues puso dicha etiqueta; si no pondría (por ejemplo) Unity... mas no estoy seguro, estoy en seguimiento de esa pregunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La etiqueta ha sido mal utilizada.

Hay que tener **mucho cuidado** con las preguntas que utilizan etiquetas de IDEs en ellas. Principalmente los usuarios nuevos, utilizan mal estas etiquetas.

### ¿Cómo identificar si la etiqueta es válida en la pregunta?

La pregunta debe ser directamente **respecto al IDE**, **alguna funcionalidad del IDE** o similar. Aquí algunos ejemplos:

- ¿Cómo filtrar archivos en el explorer interno del IDE? [Ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/14636/227)
- ¿Por qué el IDE muestra mensaje de error y no me permite realizar la operación XYZ? [Ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/2609/227), [otro ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/13890/227)
- ¿Cómo realizar FOO con el IDE? [Ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/3176/227)

Si la pregunta no encaja en uno de estos patrones o algo similar asociado directamente con el IDE, entonces **editen la pregunta para remover la etiqueta del IDE**. Pregúntate en estos casos: ¿qué pasa si un desarrollador utiliza otro IDE, acaso mi respuesta dejará de funcionar para él? ¿Acaso esta respuesta no aplica para él también solo porque usa un IDE distinto?

En el caso particular de C#, Visual Studio **no es el único IDE**. También existen otros como [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/), [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) y [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/).

Comment: O [Visual Studio Code](http://code.visualstudio.com) :)

Comment: Finalmente borré la respuesta, por carecer de sentido sin la etiqueta y porque otro usuario entendió mejor que yo lo que se preguntaba.

Answer (score 2):

Otros han explicado por qué la respuesta no es apropiada.

Pero tu respuesta está muy bien y es una lástima que se pierda.
En general aconsejo a todo aquel que escriba una respuesta que es buena pero que no se corresponde con la pregunta a:

1. Borrarla (ya lo hiciste).
2. Escribir tu mismo una pregunta apropiada y auto-responderla con esa respuesta.